# Oracle 12c Enterprise Manager Database Express Subsequent Installation on Windows Server 2012

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, enterprise-manager

I have an Oracle 12c database instance which was installed **without** the option for configuring the "`Enterprise Manager (EM) Database Express`"

How can i install it subsequent for a running instance? The Database Configuration Assistant doesn´t give me this option and the prior to 12c command `emctl` doesn´t exist anymore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17643/em_manage.htm#ADMQS032).

Comment: After following those steps in the link i can see that the port is open (netstat) but when i open the address in the browser i just get in firefox an error message "The connection was interrupted" - other browsers have similar problems

Comment: Please try with https instead of http.

Comment: i tried both: https and http
different error messages, but still no website

Comment: Please follow the steps indicated in the following MOS article: Troubleshooting Why EM Express is not Working [Article ID 1604062.1].

Comment: Thank you for your held and for this Article. Now the http EM site works, but the https access is still not possible. But this is okay for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Check the actual https port with: `select dbms_xdb_config.gethttpsport() from dual;`.

Comment: the https port is configured (on 5500) and open, but i still don´t get a response on this port.